# PHP textarea content to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to pass a textarea content to JavaScript function ,

```
<body>

////////////////////////some html //////////////////

<?php

if(isset($_POST['srchsubmet']))
{
   $query = $_POST['matrit'];

   $sqll = "SELECT * FROM mem   WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$query."%' " ;    
   $raw_results = mysqli_query( $con, $sqll)  or die(mysql_error());

   if(mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0)
   {
      while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results))
      { 
            $srch_id = $results['id']; 
            $srch_name = $results['username'];
            $srch_language = $results['language'];
            $srch_age = $results['age'];
            $srch_gender = $results['gender'];
            $srch_country = $results['country'];
            $srch_photo = $results['image'];  

echo '<div class="ana">';
echo '<div id="pho"> <img src="', $www_root, '/', $srch_photo, '" >;</div> ';
echo '<div id="info">-Name : '.$srch_name.' <br>';
echo '-Langue:'.$srch_language.'<br>';
echo '-Age:'.$srch_age.'<br>';
echo '-Contry : '.$srch_country.'';
echo '</div>';
echo '<div id="icon-call">call</div>';
echo '<div id="inter"> '.$srch_interest.' </div>';
echo '<div class="icon-message">mesage</div>';
echo '<div id="textmsg"><form method="post"><textarea id="taa"></textarea><button id="pmBtn" onClick="nn(\''.$srch_name.'\',\''.$uname.'\', taa)">Send</button></form> </div>';
echo '</div> <!-- end of ana -->                                            ';
        }


}      
  else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
            echo "No results";  }
}

?>

//////////////////////////////////some html////////////////////

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function nn(tuser, fuser, ta) {

  alert(fuser + " send to   " + tuser + " he say " +ta);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

when you type someone's name in search box all user's profile with that name appear , and when you want to send to someone message you click on message and text area appear type a message and hit send , the problem is the text that you enter in text area doesn't pass to a function that you cant store it in db or do what ever you want with it as example i display the sender's name , profile's name and the message ,but the message doesn't pass, when i use `var ta = document.getElementById("ta").value;`
for example there is two profile when i want to send message to the second profile's owner when i wrote the message and hit send it doesn't send anything because the `var ta = document.getElementById("ta").value;` pointer to the first profile's text area, so the only way to solve this problem is to pass that variable from php using something like that `<div id="textmsg"><form method="post"><textarea id="taa"></textarea><button id="pmBtn" onClick="nn(\''.$srch_name.'\',\''.$uname.'\',\'taa\')">Send</button></form>` i don't know why it can't pass the message.

Comment: Post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Comment: Nothing in your code uses the textarea contents. You're just passing PHP variables to the function.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the javascript?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Barmar , when you open the page you put some text in and hit the button , function execute , but my problem is that the text that you enter in the textarea doesn't pass to the function .

Comment: The text you enter is in `.value`, but you don't want to use that. But there's no other alternative, so your question makes no sense. PHP is all done by the time your page is rendered, it can't pass the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd sooner use this.previousSibling.value:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test(a, b, c) {
 alert(a + ' live in ' + b + ' says ' + c + ".");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$a = 'Father Christmas';
$b = 'America';
echo sprintf('<textarea>Hello</textarea><button onclick="test(%s,%s,this.previousSibling.value)">LINK</button>',htmlentities(json_encode($a)),htmlentities(json_encode($b)));
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function test(a, b, c) { 
 alert(a + " live in " + b + " say " + document.getElementById(c).value); 
}
```